# Scipy.optimize.dual_annealing not respecting bounds on variables

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

scipy.optimize.dual_annealing is not respecting the bounds on variables. I am optimizng a five-variable function; the variables at issue("nu", "vBar") are the third and fifth. python version 3.6.0, scipy version 1.4.1.

command: bounds = (
    (-1.0 / np.sqrt(2), -epsRho), (0.0 + epsH, 0.5 - epsH), **(0.0 + epsNu, 1.0)**, (0.0, 5.0), **(0.0, 1.0)**)

res = sp.optimize.dual_annealing(minFuncExact, bounds=bounds, args=args, x0=np.asarray(x0),
                                 seed=20200220,
                                 local_search_options={"method": "L-BFGS-B"})

output from running program: rho is 0.05421130947051514 H is 0.19431094432639348 **nu is 2.446853627283776** kappa is 0.21658987615448913 **vBar is -0.3671109297261478**

Initial condition x0 consists of the midpoints of the bounds intervals. Text in **bold** shows the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem too

Answer (score 0):

Two years later... better late than never, I guess.

The issue you are having is not related to the annealing part of the algorithm, but to the local search. To avoid this, you want to indicate the bounds to the local search engine.

Your new code line would be:

```
res = sp.optimize.dual_annealing(minFuncExact, bounds=bounds, args=args, x0=np.asarray(x0), seed=20200220, local_search_options={"method": "L-BFGS-B"}, "bounds": bounds)
```

Comment: For current scipy versions, `minimizer_kwargs={"method": "L-BFGS-B", "bounds": bounds},` should work.